# Gardening and Landscaping is in beta

Tags: discussion, scope

The [gardening and landscaping site](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) is now in beta.  Is it appropriate to start migrating a bunch of our slightly off topic questions over there?  If so, do the mods want a bunch of flags to deal with, or will they just go through the tags like [lawn](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn) and [grass](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grass)?

Comment: Probably best to wait until it launches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We should only migrate existing questions to a beta site if:

1. The OP requests it.
2. The question is really, really good for that site.

Otherwise there's a danger that, should the site fail, the question will be lost for ever.

That said, any *new* questions that get posted should be migrated as the beta site needs the traffic.